# Insert an IMG tag into the DOM using JavaScript and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I have the following JavaScript function that inserts an IMG tag into the DOM:

```
function createHeaderImageRight() {
    var parentElement = $("#sidebar");

    var img1 = $('<img />', {
        id: 'headerImageLeft',
        src: '/Images/Header/FGM2.jpg',
        "class": 'img-responsive headerImageLeft',
        alt: ''
    });
    img1.appendTo(parentElement);
}
```

I'd like to modify this to also include an anchor tag so that when the image is clicked, we can take the user to a URL. I'm not sure how to modify this code to include the tag I need.

Comment: you can also add an atrribute **onclick="window.location.href='http://yourdestionation.com'"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why cant you do like this..

```
$("#sidebar").append('<a href="urlToBeRedirected"><img id="headerImageLeft" src="/Images/Header/FGM2.jpg" class="img-responsive headerImageLeft"/></a>');
```

Comment: Very clean. I like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same technique that you used for your img tag.

```
var a1 = $('<a />', 
    { id: 'headerImageLeftLink',
      href: 'http://somewebsite.com'
    });
img1.appendTo(a1);
a1.appendTo(parentElement);
```

Or, you could chain the appends like so:

```
parentElement.append(a1).append(img1);
```